# How to Fix Z-Fighting When Face Has Four Bones

Tags: animation, armature, bones, three.js

I'm unsure if I'm wording my question correctly but I have a cardboard box that I am animating from flat to open to closed.

[image: Flattened]

[image: Closing]

I am then exporting it using Three.js to use on a website. I noticed there is Z-Fighting on the very bottom of the box when it is closed.

[image: No Z-Fighting]

[image: Z-Fighting]

I know why this is happening. The green face is being warped below the blue face by the skeletal animation and vice versa. I have tried fixing this by doing some weight painting (but likely have done this wrong. Here is an example of one of the sides).

[image: Weight Paint]

I'm assuming this is happening because the four bones are warping both faces so much and the distance between them is so small. Any help would be great. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Does your box have any thickness? How did you add it? Maybe add thickness *after* the deformation happens, like a *Solidify* modifier or something

Comment: @DuarteFarrajotaRamos Hi, thank you for your reply. Yes, it is only about 3mm thick though and it needs to stay that size unfortunately. The Solidfy modifier is how I achieved this.

Comment: Just as in the real world, two surfaces cannot occupy the same space. One has to be on top of the other. Think of any cardboard box or folded paper, or fabric or metal sheet. There is a top layer and a bottom one. You probably need an extra bone or some other form of fold to account for thickness. Otherwise you will get Z-fighting.

Comment: @cegaton Thank you for your reply! I was thinking a fold at the edges might help too but was hoping for a way to keep the edge simple.